# Updating Min and Max values on Md-Slider shows wrong information

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I have a very minimilistic example on codepen. I have an md-slider, with bound min and max values. The next thing i attempt to do is to use a button handler to change these bound values and also change the sliders current position.

```
//Initial setup
$scope.myslider={};
$scope.myslider.min = 100;
$scope.myslider.max =1000;
$scope.myslider.val = 500;
```

Here is my handler for the button updating the min max and selected value

```
$scope.buttonhandler = function()
{
$scope.myslider.min =0;
$scope.myslider.max =100;
$scope.myslider.val = 5;
};
```

When the button handler is triggered, the slider position is off to the extreme right. somewhere close to 100% instead of the 5%  where i expect it to be at.

Is there something wrong in my approach [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNLNEQ).

Answer (score 1):

Setting min, max and val in the same digest cycle seems to produce some weird things. I think this fixes the error:

```
$scope.myslider.min = 0;
$scope.myslider.max = 100;
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.myslider.val = 5;
}, 0);
```

That way, min and max are set first and then a valid value can be applied inside the min/max range.

Here is the fixed [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKvBNx).